# How to ensure all subjects are mapped to all the students in an excel sheet?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel sheet with students and subjects listed in it as m:n relationship.

The number of **subjects** are fixed (`6`), but the number of **students** are growing.

So basically, each student will have 6 rows for him/her, corresponding to each subject.

Sometimes it so happens, that the data entry person missies adding one subject to a student.

A monthly report is pulled (from a legacy system) and we found this error/miss.

How to quickly add the missing subjects for each student in the excel sheet?

We tried counting the number of rows by each student, but the number of students whose subjects are missed (i.e. whose row count is < 6) are way too many to fix manually.

Any excel formula which can quickly and easily do it?

example:-

```
Student    Subject

Bruce      Science

Bruce      Arts

Bruce      Maths

John       Science

John       Maths

John       Social Studies
```

So as per the above example, I want a formula which will add 2 rows, one for John with the missing Arts subject, and one for Bruce with the missing Social Studies subject.

Comment: Could you put a couple of examples, a good one and a bad one?

Comment: Why not have the subjects as columns and the students as rows?

Comment: Because the legacy system gives us the data in rows only.

Comment: @jcbermu question updated with example. Thanks

Comment: First part of correcting it will be finding the places where it is wrong. Fore that a `=COUNTIF(A:A, A2)` should work, (it look in cell A2 and finds Bruce. Tnan it counts how often Bruse is in column A. The answer should be six. Expand that formula down and you have part one of X on the road to the solution.

Comment: As for next, you write that the number of subjects is fixed. But is it always the same 6 subjects or is it a set of 6 from a larger subset?

Comment: @Hennes it is always 6 of the same subjects.

Answer (score 0):

Say we place the student names in column **A** and the subjects on the first row like:

[image]

In **H2** enter:

```
=COUNTA(B2:G2)
```

and copy down.  Then filter column **H** to find the missing items:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this can't be done, as the legacy system provides the data in rows only, like:-
Bruce   Art
Bruce   Music
John     History
John     Art
John     Science

So I want a formula, which will tell me that Bruce is missing History and science, or a formula which will add rows with Bruce with History and Bruce with Science

Comment: My own preference would be to transfer data to a MS Access (or other database) table [https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Exchange-copy-import-export-data-between-Excel-and-Access-409c27cc-c69d-461d-a74c-35392a68ed53] and query for students where count of subject < 6 [https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Access-SQL-basic-concepts-vocabulary-and-syntax-444d0303-cde1-424e-9a74-e8dc3e460671]. Databases are designed to deal well with *sets* of data, while spreadsheets work at the cell level.